# Is there a rule or standard practice for the use of units?

Tags: education

Being physics trained, we would do a problem like this:

$v=\frac{d}t$

$  =\frac{2 m}{4 s}$

$  =0.5 ms^{-1}$

Of course, being physics trained, we didn't always hold to the full conventions of mathematics.  However, I am now being told to teach the problem like this:

$v=\frac{d}t$

$  =\frac{2}{4}$

$  =0.5 ms^{-1}$

That is, without the units in the problem until the end.  Now I argue that the units help see where mistakes can occur - you can follow the units as a quick path to find where an error has crept in.  However, I have been told that it is "not mathematical convention" to use units throughout.  Is that correct?  If so, why?

Comment: In my opinion, you’re “being told” wrong. I would prefer to keep the units throughout.

Comment: @Lubin is right, +1. That’s just plain sloppy and not rigorous. Either keep the units everywhere, or omit them everywhere. You can say that $d$ is the distance measured in meters, or you can say that $d$ is the distance. The first would be $d=2$, the second would be $d=2\;m$.

Comment: I would say that the second method is okay if you feel your students have reached a certain level of comfort with units, perhaps used for second/third examples of a new procedure. But the first method is the default, eliminates confusion, highlights errors, etc.

Comment: “Highlights errors” indeed, @GregMartin. You can see at a glance when you’re adding things with different units, or when your answer has the wrong units.